# How do I make AppCode show protocol conformance?

Tags: appcode

When I use Xcode, it shows warnings telling me a class doesn't conform to a protocol. How should I make it do something similar when using AppCode?

I have searched for it, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Are you asking, how to use AppCode to make your class conform?

Comment: I have solved it.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your own answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can press shift-enter on the protocol name to bring up a menu that will ask you if you want to generate protocol stubs, or you can click inside the class and press ctrl-o which will bring up a list of all the members that you can override. Just select the ones you want.